# RxJava: call function when two observables with different result types are completed

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm working on an Android application that retrieves two different objects via an API that I access via RxJava Observables. To update the UI, I need *both* results.

How can I run a function as soon as both Observables have completed? It seems like functions like `merge` are doing what I'm planning, but as far as I can see they only work for Observables with the same result type or need a composite object that can represent both types.

A simple example:

```
Observable.just("Hello world")
        .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(String s) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        });
Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        .subscribe(new Action1<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Integer i) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        });
```

What would I need to do to run `System.out.println("Finished!")` as soon as both Observables have completed their task?

In the particular case of my Android application, I could simply store the results in the actual class, have an updateUi function that only does work when all required data already arrived and call this function from both onCompleted calls, but I feel there is a better way.

Comment: Take a look at: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html and http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html

Comment: Have a look at the .zip() operator.

Comment: `zip` would not work in this case since the first Observable returns less results than the second. I could use `combineLatest`, but that also doesn't really feel correct in this case. I just want to be notified if both Observables are finished.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I don't know why i was thinking your both sources will emit only one item. Dirty way of doing it will be creating two `Subjects` and passing event to them whenever `onCompleted` is called. Then you need to create another `Observable` where you `combineLatest` those two subjects. If that `Observable` emits item it means that both your task has done it's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 2: emitted items are processed as "side" actions, only `onCompleted` event goes through to the merged observable.

```java
Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.just("Hello world")
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .ignoreElements();
Observable<Integer> integerObservable = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .ignoreElements();

Observable.merge(stringObservable, integerObservable)
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("Finished!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                /*optionally handle if one of the observables calls onError()*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) { /*not called*/ }
        });
```

Comment: This solution is missing the Subscriptions on the initial Observables that will do the actual work - see my question. Its not that I only need to know when the calls are finished, I also need the results.

Comment: @Strayer added a new solution

Comment: While working on this again yesterday, I actually had more or less the same idea, based on your previous answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need a TaskCoordinator. Keep a simple counter in the taskCoordinator. Every time you signal a success, counter will be decremented. When the counter reaches zero, the callback will be executed. You can see my implementation like this here https://github.com/codefacts/crm-common/blob/master/src/main/java/io/crm/util/TaskCoordinator.java

It is better because, Every time you coordinate tasks, It will come to use. Reactive Stream does not have built in support for task coordination. So a promise library or Task Coordination implementation will be helpful in this case.